# Include both an image and an MP3 file in stream.publish when posting feed on Facebook

Tags: image, facebook, stream, mp3, feed

I want to include both an image and an MP3 file in `stream.publish` when I publish a feed. But according to the Facebook API reference stream attachments can include either an image or an MP3 file or Flash. Is there some way I can include both an image and an MP3 file in my feed?